# GridView - Hide Column but Use Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working with a GridView that I'm populating programmatically. In order to access the ID value, I have to have it as one of the columns (as opposed to a ListBox, where I was able to assign the value to each entry in a hidden way). Is there a way to hide that ID column, but still use the value?

The columns are being auto-generated through the code and I'm accessing the ID value using DataKeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general overview of what you can do. It's not complicated. You databind as usual, but while doing that you find the index of the ID column. Then you use that index to hide the column on the RowCreated event. If you search for how to hide a column using auto-generated columns, you'll run into several answers following the method I'm using for hiding.

```
Private IDColumnIndex As Integer      //Class scope - we need to use it in multiple methods

Public Sub PageLoad() Handles Me.Load //or wherever your databind is happening
    Dim source As New DataTable()
    IDColumnIndex = source.Columns("id").Ordinal   //Gets column index of "ID" column

    view.DataSource = source
    view.DataBind()
End Sub

//Hide our "ID" auto-generated column.
Public Sub view_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles view.RowCreated
    e.Row.Cells(IDColumnIndex).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified C#. It should not be drastically different, so I'll try to work with this anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm populating the GridView using a List, not a DataTable. This seems to differ because List doesn't have the Columns array. I tried to access it from the GridView AFTER assigning it to the DataSource, but it didn't work out because I need the index to work with the Columns array.

Comment: I see. I wrote it in VB just to give you the idea before you tagged it C#, and also not knowing your data source type I was just illustrating that you need the index of the ID column to use later. If you know that the index of the ID column will always be 5 (for example) you could hard code it into the RowCreated handler, which is not as nice but depending on your scenario may work for you. Retrieving that ID column index all depends on what the Type is of the objects in your List of course.

Comment: The ID column will always be the first column entered. Does that mean it will be 0? I agree that it's not as nice, but it seems like it would work in this situation. Each object being entered as a row is of type MyObject, which has 4 properties (ALL strings) and each of its properties is entered into a column when the List of MyObjects is set as the DataSource for the GridView.

Each column value is a string, but it is being added as a whole row, which represents one object of type MyObject.

Comment: I see. In that case, yeah, go ahead and use 0 as the index and that should work for you. It may be a little more difficult otherwise to programatically retrieve that index (I'd have to look up how to to be honest). If it doesn't work, I'd like to hear why. Good luck!

Comment: This worked perfectly. The index was actually 1, because I have selection enabled, and the Select column counts as column 0. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to have this not occur on the last row? When I enable paging, this hides the whole "page number" row.

Comment: Inside view_RowCreated, try wrapping the code with this:
if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager)

Answer (score 2):

Assign the ID to the DataKeyNames collection will work fine, is that an issue for you?  The data keys is available for each row, not showing up in the UI, but still accessible with the row data, so you can get the ID for each row.  You just have to get it from the DataKeys collection, instead of the row directly.

You can add code to hide the first column (the ID) so that it doesn't appear, and rely on using the datakeynames to get the ID value...  if that doesn't work, could you elaborate on why so I can adjust my answer..

Comment: I'm able to access the ID using `PanelGridView.SelectedDataKey["id"]`, so how can I now hide the column? I should add that all I've added to the DataKeys is the DataKeyNames which it seems to obtain from the auto-generated columns...is there a way to put it right in the DataKeys instead of just specifying the names to take from the auto-generated columns?

Comment: You don't have to have a column  if it's in the DataKeyNames collection; I do it all the time.  But if you want, I think you can say Visible="false" on the column in markup, so it's hidden, or use a CSS style="display:none" using the item/header/alt item/footer styles.

Comment: If you are using auto generated columns, you could hide the first column, or even remove the column too via `Columns.Remove(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID value if you add the ID column to the DataKeyNames property of your GridView. [msdn link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

```
myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across that array earlier but didn't think to call it's Value for whatever reason. I was also able to access the ID just now using `PanelGridView.SelectedDataKey["id"]`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did add the ID value to the DataKeyNames property of the GridView. However, if I don't add the ID values to the GridView, it claims there's no value for "ID".

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a visible column But then make the template for the colmn jus a space or something.  Then in the ID for the column, I put the ID I want to track.  This technique let's me easily find the ID of a row using javascript when the content has been rendered into HTML.

If you let the grid view do its business rendering with the hidden data keys, you may never find the ID in client side browser javascript in all that mess.